# Combining positive and negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am working with python and have to tackle several option of key order in a dict to clean out single quotes. The dict is right now still a string because of the messy single-quote situation I cann not transform it to a dict.

So for example cleaning the *name* for the first option is easy and done by

```
df.loc[:,'general_data'].str.replace(r"('name': ')(.*)(', 'phone')", 
                                            lambda x: x.group(1) + x.group(2).replace("'", "") + x.group(3), regex=True)
```

This solves the first combination seen here

```
"{'city': '1111 Doecity', 'name': 'Ben's Carrepair', 'phone': '0211222222', 'street': 'Unter'm Bobbele 39'}"
```

So all unnecassary single-quotes are removed. and the result for *name* is

```
Bens Carrepair
```

IF there is no *phone number* *street* should be used the same way name is used before.

The second string option is:

```
"{'city': '1111 Doecity', 'name': 'Ben's Carrepair', 'street': 'Unter'm Bobbele 39'}"
```

So my question is how can i combine lookaheads like an **IF - ELSE* - strucure* so that if there is no phone number the group is limited to *'street'* like in the working example until *'phone'*

The data shown here is contained inside a pandas dataframe column.
If there any requests feel free to ask. I#m not working a lot with regex usually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
pattern = r"(?<='name': ').*?(?=', '(?:street|phone)')"
df['general_data'].str.replace(pattern,  lambda x: x.group().replace("'", ""))
```

Namely, you can simplify the replacement by using lookarounds in the pattern that will match the least amount of chars between `'name': '` and `', 'street'` or `', 'phone'`and you will only need to remove `'` in Group 0, the whole match.

Comment: OH yes thanks! I tried it in another way adding an | which did not work as I hoped. But this is what I searched for thanks!